# Firebase Snapshot object to raw json

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way we can convert or obtain a Firebase snapshot object (`FIRDataSnapshot`) as raw JSON, so that it may more easily be converted to models using mappers.?

I would like to know if anyone has serialized a snapshot object to JSON using `JSONSerialization`, and then using the mappers. Also, are there any underlying implications of such conversions and using it?

Comment: Huh idk about converting to raw JSON but you should be able to map snapshot's [String : Any?] value to custom model with ObjectMapper. Have you tried that or do you need raw JSON?

Comment: I havent found any ObjectMapper which does that. Has anyone got any success ?